# multiple, concurrent jQuery effects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I am trying to apply some fancy looking UI stuff to my web application, and I want a menu that, slides down and fades in, or, slides up and fades out at the same time

I tried this...

```
if($('#Menu').css("display") == "none") {
    $('#Menu').slideDown(250).fadeIn(250);
} else {
    $('#Menu').slideUp(250).fadeOut(250);
}
```

...it didn't work. Only one effect occurs...Can anyone explain if it is possible to chain together effects in this way, or suggest a workaround?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to do it with the .animate method rather than slideDown and fadeIn. What's currently happening is one effect occurs, then the next one occurs because jQuery UI uses an animation queue system. Only one queue item executes at a time per element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acheive this you'll want to use jQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. Something like this;

```
if ($('#Menu').css('opacity') == 1) {
    $('#Menu').animate({
        opacity: 0,
        height: '0'
    }, 500, function() {
        // animation complete
    });
} else {
    $('#Menu').animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: '200px'
    }, 500, function() {
        // animation complete
    });
}​
```

I think you could possibly replace the height value with 'toggle' to avoid putting in specific values. However I've not used it personally so can't be sure.

**EDIT:**
'toggle' seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RjESG/3/